# ADGroups AND ADusers

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-to-excel

I need to get the following into a CSV:

**Groups with fields:** group name, group SID, group email address, group type

and then for each of the above groups i need the member users with the fields: group name (I know that's a repeat), userID, user firstname, userlastname, user email.

If someone has a solution for this I will be forever grateful.  The solution will be something I can study and learn from so thanks again.

I have the two pieces separately but am stuck at that point

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Member |
    select Name, DistinguishedName, sid, GroupCategory, GroupScope,
        @{Name="Members";Expression={($_.Members | Measure-Object).Count}} |
    Out-GridView
    #Export-Csv c:\rmm-mgmt\test.csv
```

I don't understand why the user details can't just be added as well.
For the users I'm using:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * |
    Select-Object name, surname, givenname, displayname, emailaddress |
    Out-GridView
```

(Using `Out-GridView` to check results before I begin exporting)

As you can see these are two pieced of information I can get but can't put them together.  One example is I can't get the list of members in groups.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you try something to solve your issue? Post the code you have made so far.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: [`Get-AdGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps), [`Get-AdGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps), [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6). AD groups don't have email address.

Comment: @RemusRusanu a mail-enabled security group can have an email address though

Comment: The reason you can't simply export user properties from AD group membership is that a group only contains **references** to the user objects (by distinguishedName). It doesn't contain the actual user objects. 

Essentially, you need to get the user object names first from the group, then you have a list of object names to query for the rest of the user properties you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ForEach-Object` and assign the group to a named variable so you can access it where you format each member. Then pipe `$_.Member` into `Get-ADUser`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Member | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    $_.Member | Get-ADUser -Properties Surname,GivenName,DisplayName,EmailAddress |
        Select @{N = "Group Name";E = {$group.Name}}, Surname, GivenName, DisplayName, EmailAddress
} | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Everyone...thanks so much!!  This worked for me and I've learned a few things too.   Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on the exact output formatting you are looking for but I believe something like this should work for what you are attempting to do.

```
# Create an empty array we will add our custom objects to.
$outputObjs = @()

# Get all the AD groups.
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties Member | 
            select Name, DistinguishedName, sid, GroupCategory, GroupScope |
            select -First 40

# Iterate the groups capturing the members of each group.
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    $groupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name |
                        ? { $_.objectClass -eq "user" } | 
                        % { Get-ADUser $_.SamAccountName } | 
                        select name, surname, givenname, displayname, emailaddress

    # Get the group member count
    $memCount = 0
    if ($groupMembers) { $memCount = $groupMembers.Count; } 
    else { $memCount = 0 }

    # Iterate through the group members creating a custom object and adding it to our object array.
    foreach($member in $groupMembers) {
        $outputObjs += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property (@{
            'Group Name' = $group.Name;
            'Group DN' = $group.DistinguishedName;
            'Group SID' = $group.SID;
            'Group Category' = $group.GroupCategory;
            'Group Scope' = $group.GroupScope;
            'Group Member Count' = $memCount
            'User Name' = $member.name;
            'User Surname' = $member.surname;
            'User Given Name' = $member.givenname;
            'User Display Name' = $member.displayname;
            'User Email Address' = $member.emailaddress
        })
    }
}

# Convert the object array to a CSV.
$outputObjs | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Your CSV would look like this

```
"Group Name","User Surname","User Given Name","Group Member Count","User Email Address","Group SID","User Name","Group Category","Group DN","User Display Name","Group Scope"
```